# Carousel not loading within Ajax Tab on document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, carousel

So I have a carousel that is on a external page which is pulled in when an Ajax tab is clicked on the main page, that carousel doesn't show up until I refresh the page. Is there someway I can get it to show up?? Is there something wrong with my javascript code here. This page is also on an asp.net server if that makes any difference.

The carousel is within Why CEC
http://testing.morecleanenergy.com/step_1

This is what I have on the main page where the tabs are, it's at the bottom of the page..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ajax-tab-container').easytabs();
  $("#tabs2").load('/tab2.html');
  $("#tabs3").load('/tab3b.html');
  $("#tabs4").load('/tab4.html');
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      navigation : true,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem : true
      });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me, please make sure you browser not caching! I tested it on Firefox and Chrome on Windows 8

Comment: It works for me after I refresh the page, but if I just go straight to tab 3 when the page is loaded nothing is there. :( I've cleared my cache and tried it across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You've got this error:

```
ReferenceError: Sys is not defined (line 44, column 8)
```

That means the line 44 is randomly breaking your JavaScript execution:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

So this error ocurrs:

```
$(...).owlCarousel is not a function
```

And your Carousel is not rendered.

Try to remove or repair the line 44, and you'll get rid of this trouble.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea what that is... you think for sure thats the reason why my javascript isn't executing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I suppose the more secure way to go is avoid this JS errors and see if it keeps happening.